# CSS3 circular animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I did a CSS3 circular animated menu with the menu items starting from the left end and rotates to the right to their corresponding locations.
I have put each of the menu items inside a container and made each container to rotate to different angles to bring out the animation.
What my problem is since each menu item is inside a container, there would be as many as containers as there are menu items which makes it impossible to get the `:hover` action for the anchor tag inside each menu item since the container is in the top.
Can someone suggest a fix for this?

You can see it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/blueeyes/bWWHm/4/

You can see that I am able hover the links `aa` and `fff` because `aa` doesn't have a container and the container of `fff` is on top of all.
The other links are under the container so not accessible.

Comment: Please show some code and/or link an example so we can see what's going on.

Comment: @Kolink : i have updated the question with fiddle link. Please see it.
http://jsfiddle.net/blueeyes/bWWHm/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things, you don't need a container. You just position all menu items absolutely at the center of the circle, then you rotate each one by the desired angle, translate it outwards by the radius of the circle and then rotate it again by the opposite angle to make the text horizontal again. In this way, the center of each menu item is going to be on the circle.

## [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/fdLon)

**HTML**:

```
<ul class='circ-menu'>
  <li><a href='#'>aa</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>bb</a></li>
  <!-- and so on -->
</ul>
```

**CSS**:

```
.circ-menu {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  width: 10em; height: 10em;
  list-style: none;
}
.circ-menu li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  margin: -1.5em;
  width: 3em; height: 3em;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
}
.circ-menu li:first-child {
  transform: rotate(-112.5deg) translateY(-5em) rotate(112.5deg);
}
.circ-menu li:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(-67.5deg) translateY(-5em) rotate(67.5deg);
}
/* and so on */
```

Comment: This method is good but we won't get a smooth circular animation(flickering) using this. That was the reason i chose the other one.

Comment: What exactly do you want to animate and how?

Comment: Actually i implemented the menu using the logic you mentioned. I used transition to animate, from initial point to the final point. It does animate but not exactly in a circular manner. Could you pm me in blueeyes4ya@gmail.com if you are fine with it.

Comment: Animating an element in a perfect circular manner can be done like this http://dabblet.com/gist/4389712

Comment: Thanks for that. Will surely go through this. :)
btw isnt it possible using transition without using animation key frames ?

Comment: Yes, you could do that. Just use the content of the 0% keyframe for the normal state and the content of the 100% keyframe for the active state. However, if you're counting just on CSS and your transition is triggered by hover, when the element moves, the mouse will no longer be over it => no more hover state, transition doesn't complete and the element goes back to its initial position. But if you're adding something like an active class via JavaScript and you don't remove it until you add it to another menu item, then it should work just fine using just transitions.

Comment: Ok. Please have a look into this.
http://jsfiddle.net/abhilashv/jEB5D/
Just comment off the animation starting line, see the position of the element, then start the animation. Why does the animation start from a different point like some position below the actual position it should start from. ?

Comment: Because that's where it should start from. Rotated by -90deg around a point that's on the same vertical line as its right side and 200px below its top side.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25639/discussion-between-abhilash-v-and-ana)

Comment: I got the issue fixed. 
I used translation and rotation to smoothen the animation. 
Thanks a lot Ana. :)